# How to make video player size smaller ?

Tags: react-native

I use `react-native-video-player` and I have difficulties with adjusting size of video player, it's too big and doesn't fit into screen and control buttons doesn't fit into available space.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-player';

export default class VideoPage extends Component {

  render() {
   return (
    <View>
      <VideoPlayer
        video={{ uri: 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/sample_video.mp4' }}
        videoWidth={1280}
        videoHeight={720}
      />
    </View>
   );
  }
}
```

Here is what I have now, as you can see this is NOT OK.

[image]

I need some help with how to make it smaller. I tried to specify width & height as you can see, but it just doesn't change anything it stays as it is. Maybe there is something I don't know ?

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Is videoWidht and videoHeight not working?

Comment: @skAstro exactly, they don't work. Any sizes I set up here don't apply and don't make any change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set size to your view not your videoplayer and do it by styling.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-player';

export default class VideoPage extends Component {

  render() {
   return (
    <View style={{width: 1280, height: 720}}>
      <VideoPlayer
        video={{ uri: 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/sample_video.mp4' }}

      />
    </View>
   );
  }
}
```